# After yesterday's phonegap 3.0 plugin re-install, the capture plugin now crashes on android "Unfortunately, {app} has stopped."

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, media, capture

After yesterday's phonegap 3.0 plugin re-install, the capture plugin now crashes on android "Unfortunately, {app} has stopped."

The capture plugin was working just fine on build before this.

But now after re-installing all the plugins and re-setting the app up from scratch.  The app builds fine.  I can capture video or images, but when choosing to save the image or video, the app crashes reporting "Unfortunately, {app} has stopped." instead of returning the image or video to the next process. i.e. captureSuccess() {} callback function

It never makes it to captureFailure callback function, the app actually crashes out and closes.

If you cancel the video or image capture, after capturing, it will return back to the captureFailure callback function with the error code that the operation was cancelled.

So what is my question?  Has something changed with the new version of the capture plugin.

I noticed that something was different because in the plugins folder, instead of the plugin folder being called org.apache.cordova.core.media-capture it's now called org.apache.cordova.media-capture  so I suspect that the new folder naming convention is not the only thing that has changed. At most the older plugin version was a week ago, and this one is new as of the date of this post.

I do have to reinstall plugins periodically.  For some reason the android.json file in the plugins folder gets corrupted now and then.  Usually surrounding the install of more plugins.   When this happens the app will no longer build and install and so I redo the app from scratch pulling it down from the repo and then installing all the plugins via a shell script that I made to automate this.

Anyone else having this crashing problem?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?  All other plugins seems to be working just fine.  Just having a problem with the capture plugin.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, except the capture plugin won't even install properly. I just get `TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings`.

Comment: I received that message if I tried removing, then reinstalling the capture plugin, however my app was actually non-functional at that point.  So I redid the project from scratch by backing up the folder then pulling it fresh from the repo and re-setup everything for phonegap.  You can see my solution to get this far at....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969360/phonegap-capture-plugin-capturevideo-not-working-phonegap-3-0-0-0-14-3/18983401#18983401 But also this presented the problem above.  Still no help

Comment: In my console, I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Do not perform IO operations on the UI thread. Use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool() instead.`